# Determine the geometric centre of a circle with a quarter missing

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

### The question

I have a circle of radius $a$, (where $a$ is a known positive constant), centred at Cartesian coordinates $(a,a)$. The bottom left quarter of the circle is missing.

Let the two-dimensional region $R$ be formed by this circle with a missing quarter. I'd like to compute the geometric centre of the region $R$ (or the centre of mass if we were to assume it has uniform density $\rho(x,y)=1)$.

### My attempt

I know that for uniform density, the geometric centre of a region $R$, $(\bar x, \bar y)$ is

$$\bar x={1\over|R|}\iint_Rx\,\mathrm dA$$
$$\bar y={1\over|R|}\iint_Ry\,\mathrm dA$$
where $|R|$ is the area of the region. I got the area of the region by $|R|=\frac{3\pi a^2}{4}$.

I recognise that these integrals are better suited to be calculated in polar coordinates so I parametrise as such:

$$\begin{cases}x&=a\cos(\theta)+a\\y&=a\sin(\theta)+a\end{cases}$$

where $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq\theta\leq\pi$.

I will then show a calculation for $\bar x$, which is erroneous (the calculation for $\bar y$ is the same):

$$\begin{align*}\bar x&={1\over |R|}\iint_R x\,\mathrm dA\\&={1\over |R|}\int_?^?\int_?^?(a\cos(\theta)+a)\,\mathrm da\,\mathrm d\theta\end{align*}$$
I think I may have made a mistake setting up the integral limits--this part confuses me:
$$\begin{align*}&={1\over |R|}\int_{-\pi\over 2}^\pi\int_0^a(a\cos(\theta)+a)\,\mathrm da\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\frac{4}{3\pi a^2}\times\frac{3\pi a^2+2a}{4}\\&=\frac{2+3\pi}{4}\end{align*}$$
which does not even depend on $a$. I have clearly done something wrong.

Comment: Don't forget the Jacobian when you change coordinates: $\mathrm{d}A = \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y = r \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta$

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something here, but  can’t you just translate the circle to $(0,0)$, perform your integral, then translate back $(a,a)$?

Comment: Could you please make a drawing or clarify whether you're talking about a circle or a disc? You use the word circle but then you mention "area" (the area of a circle is 0) and you use double integrals.

Comment: One can use "effective" way of thinking about missing quarter as an additional quarter with negative mass, but we still should know location of center of mass of this quarter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose polar coordinates centered at the center of your circle so the change-of-variables looks like
\begin{cases} 
x = a + r \cos \theta, \\
y = a + r \sin \theta. 
\end{cases}
Notice that when $r=0$, we're at the center $(x, y) = (a, a)$. As you correctly observed, the region of interest is defined by the inequalities
$$
0 \leq r \leq a 
\quad \text{and} \quad 
-\tfrac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \pi. 
$$
The Jacobian determinant for the change of variables to these shifted polar coordinates are the same as for standard polar coordinates:
$$
\frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(r, \theta)} 
= 
\left\lvert 
\begin{matrix}
\partial x/ \partial r & \partial x/ \partial \theta \\
\partial y/ \partial r & \partial y/ \partial \theta 
\end{matrix}
\right\rvert
=
\left\lvert 
\begin{matrix}
\cos \theta & -r \sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & r \cos \theta 
\end{matrix}
\right\rvert
= r \, (\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta)
= r 
$$
Let's calculate $\bar{x}$ since, by symmetry, $\bar{y} = \bar{x}$.
\begin{align}
\bar{x} &= \frac{1}{\frac{3}{4} \pi a^2} 
\int_{-\tfrac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} \int_0^a (a + r\cos\theta)\, r \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \frac{4}{3 \pi a^2} 
\int_{-\tfrac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} \int_0^a (ar + r^2\cos\theta) \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \frac{4}{3 \pi a^2} 
\int_{-\tfrac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} \left.\biggl( \frac{ar^2}{2} 
+ \frac{r^3\cos\theta}{3} \biggr)\right\rvert_0^a \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \frac{4}{3 \pi a^2} \cdot \frac{a^3}{6} 
\int_{-\tfrac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} \bigl( 3 + 2\cos\theta \bigr) \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \frac{2a}{9 \pi} \Bigl. \bigl( 3\theta + 2\sin\theta \bigr) 
\Bigr\rvert_{-\tfrac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi} \\
&= \frac{2a}{9 \pi} \cdot \biggl( 3 \cdot \frac{3\pi}{2} + 2 \cdot 1 \biggr) \\
&= \frac{(9\pi + 4) \, a}{9 \pi}
\end{align}
[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ahek3v8ckj)'s an interactive picture. You can drag the center of the circle and see the center of mass.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using uniform density, moving the circle should not be a problem, so re-center it at the origin, and now it is clear by symmetry that the center of mass will lie along the line $x=y$. $R$ can now be seen as $0 \le r \le a$ and $-\pi/2 < t < \pi$, yielding the integral
$$
\iint_R x\ dA = \int_{r=0}^{r=a} \int_{t=-\pi/2}^{t=\pi} r \cos (t)r\ drdt,
$$
since $x = r\cos t$ and $dA = r\ drdt$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure the outer integral limits are $r=0$ to $r=1$ and not $r=0$ to $r=a$ since our circle's radius is $a$?

Comment: @javan.g fixed thanks!